# How to throw away lines of text with specific characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have multiple `.log` files that look like:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2020-04-02 00:09:16
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-04-02 00:14:16 172.31.11.70 GET /ben_laptop_Apple.html - 443 - 156.154.81.54 curl/7.54.0 - 404 0 2 28
...
2020-04-02 00:19:16 172.31.11.70 GET /ben_laptop_Apple.html - 443 - 123.123.23.23 curl/7.54.0 - 404 0 2 47
```

I want to parse and concatenate the fields to get a nicely formatted Pandas table. To that end, I have the following working well:

```
# Match the extension pattern and save the list of file names in the ‘all_filenames’ variable.
extension = 'log'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

# Use pandas to concatenate all files in the list and export as CSV. The output file is named “combined_csv.csv” located in your working directory.
fields = 'date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken'.split(' ')

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=' ', header=None, skiprows=4, names=fields) for f in all_filenames ])
```

As you can see, I skip the first 4 rows to remove the header text. However, the problem is that a single log file will have the header text repeated throughout the `.log` file. So my files actually look like:

```
    #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
    #Version: 1.0
    #Date: 2020-04-02 00:09:16
    #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
    2020-04-02 00:14:16 172.31.11.70 GET /ben_laptop_Apple.html - 443 - 156.154.81.54 curl/7.54.0 - 404 0 2 28
    ...
    #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
    #Version: 1.0
    #Date: 2020-04-02 00:09:16
    #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
    ...
    2020-04-02 00:19:16 172.31.11.70 GET /ben_laptop_Apple.html - 443 - 123.123.23.23 curl/7.54.0 - 404 0 2 47
```

How do I filter out the repeating header text? I'm guessing I need a RegEx solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `skiprows=4` you should use the `comment='#'`. This way your `pd.read_csv` will skip the rows that begins with `#`:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=' ', header=None, comment='#', names=fields) for f in all_filenames ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you:

`df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.csv', comment='#')`

From the documentation:

`comment : str, default None`

> Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the
>   beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. This
>   parameter must be a single character. Like empty lines (as long as
>   skip_blank_lines=True), fully commented lines are ignored by the
>   parameter header but not by skiprows. For example, if comment=’#’,
>   parsing ‘#emptyna,b,cn1,2,3’ with header=0 will result in ‘a,b,c’
>   being treated as the header.